# C# Only refresh PictureBox/Panel when tell them to refresh?

Tags: c#, refresh, panel, picturebox, paint

I'm making a bomberman game in a C# windows form application. It has over 300 pictureboxes (walls) that are placed on a panel. The picturebox of bomberman himself is also on that panel.

When the location of bombermans picturebox changes, all the controls on the panel are automatically refreshed. Because there are so many controls on that panel, and because the location of the picturebox changes multiple times per second, the program becomes laggy when I try to move.

I want to have control over the refresh event of the panel (and it's controls), because I think my problem is solved when only the pictureboxes that need to be refreshed, are refreshed programmatically.

I hope someone can help me out with this!

Ruud.

Comment: Don't use picture boxes.  Override the form's OnPaint() method and use e.Graphics.DrawImage() to draw the walls.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the child, the parent has to be refreshed because it may need to draw the area where child was located previously. It would also mean that all children (of parent) would get refreshed.

OTH, using so many controls may not be a good idea. I would suggest you to keep data structures describing walls and then use it to draw it within Panel (or your custom control). You can write your own logic for hit testing (mouse or keyboard click within wall boundary) by capturing mouse/keyboard events at Panel/Parent level. With correct organization data structure, hit testing can be very efficient.

Comment: No argument with the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to paint the whole form which will surely take time . If you want to change only a part of the form, which in your case is Moving the bomberman to a new position, Only invalidate the area you want to repaint and then pass it to the Invalidate method.

Do something similar to this.

```
//Invalidate previous position of bomberman
Rectangle invalid = new Rectangle(picturebox1.Location.x,picturebox1.Location.y,picturebox1.Width,picturebox1.Height);
Invalidate(invalid);
//Add code to move your picture box and then call above two lines again
invalid = new Rectangle(picturebox1.Location.x,picturebox1.Location.y,picturebox1.Width,picturebox1.Height);
Invalidate(invalid);
```

Note sure but somthing similar polished code would work...

Here is a link to an example for reference. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229628.aspx

Comment: This already happens automatically without writing any code at all.

Comment: @Hans Passant. I had a feeling that when you specify a new position for a control the repainting is done automatically but was not sure about it thanx...